# Can I answer a 112 rejection of a method claim by making it less specific?

Tags: method, claim-construction, rejection, 112

A patent with the composition claims has already issued (11,090,320), and this is a divisional. My main method claim as filed has the steps of (among others)—

*Original claim --*

**A method for reducing methylation of a subject’s mitochondrial DNA, comprising the steps of:
(a)     providing at least one promoter for mitochondrial fission and at least one promoter for mitochondrial biogenesis, and optionally providing at least one promoter for demethylase;
(b)     a first delay interval;
(c)     etc.**

The examiner based his 112 rejection on these promoters, which I provided examples of in the spec. Can I simply eliminate the promoters to eliminate the 112 rejection? Like so —

*Proposed new claim --*

**A method for reducing methylation of a subject’s mitochondrial DNA, comprising the steps of:
(a)     promoting mitochondrial fission;
(b) promoting mitochondrial biogenesis, and optionally promoting demethylase;

and after a first delay interval;
(c)     etc.**

Comment: Can you add any more context without telling the world more than you would like to? If it has been published we can look it all up in PAIR and possibly give a better answer.

Comment: I've added the number of the parent patent above, and more of the claim in question.

Comment: I looked up the parent application in PAIR, the divisional is not yet published. I am not posting this as an answer because it would take study of the divisional claims and the rejection that I can't see and the original spec that I haven't OCR'd. Also very far from my field. I would say that your proposed wording is broader that the rejected version. I was impressed with my quick look at the Image File Wrapper. Not many pro-se applicants get something sophisticated granted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Can I answer a 112 rejection by making it less specific?**

Yes, if the claim refers to something specific that is not supported in the specification then amending to a less specific wording that *is* supported in the specification might fix a 112 (indefinitness) rejection and result in a broader claim if warranted.

It is hard to know if your specific case will be solved with your proposed amendment without study of the application and office action.

Comment: Thanks, George. I think I'm entitled to a broad claim, so I plan to submit all new claims, with one new independent claim using the broader language. We'll see.

Answer (score 0):

So this is what happened: I submitted the broader claims and the examiner withdrew them from consideration, saying they were similar to claims he restricted out previously. He's right, though his initial restriction was improper, in my opinion. I traversed it, but didn't matter. I suppose I laid myself open to that in the way I wrote the independent claims.  In the future I will submit just one overarching independent claim in a divisional and avoid restriction to begin with. That you can submit three independent claims for free doesn't mean you should.

The other claims have received a final rejection. I will argue them again with an AFCP request, and if that doesn't work, I will appeal.

Comment: In my opinion this is where good patent attorneys earns their fees. Getting claims granted is a negotiation.